# JQuery/AJAX Toggle Switch POST to php file without navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to get this working using several methods such as $.ajax in Javascript and using a jQuery plugin found here: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

I have scoured stackoverflow and google for a solution but to no avail.

Basically what I am trying to do is make a toggle switch (enable/disable) that when clicked, sends the result via AJAX to a PHP script without navigating or reloading the page.

One of these toggle switches to be precise: http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Below I can get it to run the PHP script when the checkbox is "toggled" but it navigates to the blank PHP file page (I don't have the PHP script doing anything on success).

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="classes/commons/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <form  id="form" method="post" action="audio_alarm.php"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" checked>
  </form>
  <script>
    $('#toggle').change(function(){
      $('#form').submit(); 
    });
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Now below is what I thought should make it work for sure but the jQuery plugin doesn't seem to be working as advertised.. Unless I've made a simple oversight..

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript"     src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="classes/commons/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 


</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="audio_alarm.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" checked>
  </form>
  <script>
    $('#toggle').change(function(){
      // submit the form 
      $(#myForm).ajaxSubmit(); 
      // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
      return false; 
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're returning false on the change event, not the submit. Look [here](https://github.com/malsup/form#ajaxsubmit-options-)

Comment: That appears to only work if the user clicks a submit button, I'm not using a submit button..

Comment: Now your code is right, But you can't see any changes because you don't have event handler after jQuery post succeeds.

Comment: The PHP script inputs an entry into my database, so when I use the first code block it makes the entry but when using the .ajaxSubmit code it does not input the entry..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is the complete solution for you.

HTML

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript"     src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="classes/commons/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 


  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="audio_alarm.php" method="post"> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" checked>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="heading"></div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="body"></div>
  </div>
    <div></div>
    <script>
      $('#toggle').change(function(){
        var mode= $(this).prop('checked');
        // // submit the form 
        // $(#myForm).ajaxSubmit(); 
        // // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
        // return false; 
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          dataType:'JSON',
          url:'audio_alarm.php',
          data:'mode='+mode,
          success:function(data)
          {
            var data=eval(data);
            message=data.message;
            success=data.success;
            $("#heading").html(success);
            $("#body").html(message);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

When you enable or disable button it makes `ajax` call to `audio_alarm.php`.And data are retrieved using ajax.Hope it will help you a lot.

code for `audio_alarm.php` is as follows:

```
 <?php

$mode=$_POST['mode'];

if ($mode=='true') //mode is true when button is enabled 
{
    //Retrive the values from database you want and send using json_encode
    //example
    $message='Hey my button is enabled!!';
    $success='Enabled';
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'success'=>$success));
}

else if ($mode=='false')  //mode is false when button is disabled
{
    //Retrive the values from database you want and send using json_encode
    //example
    $message='Hey my button is disabled!!';
    $success='Disabled';
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'success'=>$success));

} 
 ?>
```

Comment: Typo: '$success' above should be 'success' in the json_encode above.